# How to move a movieclip along a custom path in Flash?

Tags: adobe-flash

I got a movieclip, and I got a custom path (some curves imported from Illustrator)

How can I "attach" my movieclip so each frame it advances over a segment of the curve?.

If you need a more detailed explanation I can draw a picture.

Comment: Please, do not use Flash anymore.
It is outdated technology.

Comment: @Patrick Flash is still used heavily in video game development in conjunction with Scaleform. It ain't dead yet! ;)

Comment: @Patrick if you mean Actionscript, you are wrong. And if you mean Flash Pro, you are more than wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Draw a path on its own layer
2. Cut your path <kbd>Cmd / Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
3. Have your MovieClip Layer Selected
4. Create the desired length of the animation and `Insert Frames`
5. Then select your Movieclip, right click and Create Motion Tween
6. Paste in place your path
7. Go back to Frame 1 and then in the Properties panel under Rotation choose Orient to Path